# What is efficient and fastest way to get number of records( no. of lines) in zip file using aws s3 command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, boto

I want to get number of records in zip file which is present in s3 bucket. Could you please tell me what is the fastest way to get the result?

I am running below command but that is not working. Please correct me if I am doing anything wrong.

```
aws s3 cp s3://itx-agu-lake/raw/vs-1/load-1619/data/phd_admsrc.txt.gz - | wc -l
```

The above command is giving me 0. but actual count is 24.

Comment: That's not a zip file (which is a compressed archive). That's a gzip compressed text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decompress the .gz file:

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucket/object.gz - | zcat | wc -l
```

This copies the S3 object to stdout, sends it through `zcat` to decompress, then send the output to `wc` to count the lines.